# How to convert a php array into a .txt file

Tags: php

Here's a php array and I want to convert it into a .txt file (text file) through php with specific headers.
Please help me!

Array :

```
$array = [
"fname" => "Jon",
"lname" => "Snow",
"class" => "Six",
"School" => "Abc"
];
```

Headers : "FirstName" "LastName" "Class" "School"

.txt file should be like this :

```
FirstName  LastName  Class  School
Jon         Snow      Six     Abc
```

I have tried below one but this will not work for .txt file

```
 public static function ChangeArrayToTxt($result)
    {
        $basePath = dirname(\Yii::getAlias('@frontend')).'/var';
        $filename="details.txt";
        $file_path=$basePath.'/'.$filename;

        if (!file_exists($basePath)) {

            mkdir($basePath, 0777,true);
            $output = fopen($file_path, "w");
            chmod($file_path,0777);
            fputcsv($output, array('FirstName', 'LastName', 'Class', 'School),"\t");
            $upload['success']="FULFILLMENT CSV Uploaded";
            fwrite($output, print_r($result,true));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `json_encode($array, true)`. It will convert your php array to JSON wich can be stored in a text file. But that's all I can say because there is no snippet from what you have tried.

Comment: I recommend using CSV format. Should I edit the post accordingly

Comment: @Variable and Krishanu, Actually I know how to convert it into csv . But I have to convert it into .txt file. And I searched for that  but i didn't get it. That's why I am asking here.

Comment: As csv file IS a text file. csv is a way to structure numbers and strings within a text file in a format that programs will know how to read. If you use what you know about converting to csv, but name the file with .txt for an ending, it will be a csv formatted txt file.

Comment: Okay  Marc Maxson. Thanks , I will try this way

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php 
$txt1 = "";
$txt2 = "";

$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

$colors = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");

foreach ($colors as $key => $value) {
  $txt1=$txt1."$key ";
}
echo " ";
foreach ($colors as $key => $value) {
  $txt2 = $txt2."$value ";
}

$txt = $txt1."<\n>".$txt2;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
header("Location: /newfile.txt");
die();
?>
```